# Has my App been hacked? Mysterious DOM manipulation injects Flash

Tags: javascript, malware

In testing my local code, the following appears in my DOM ~2 seconds after loading:

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1px; height: 1px; z-index: 2147483647;" id="_GPL_e6a00_parent_div">
  <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="_GPL_e6a00_swf" data="http://savingsslider-a.akamaihd.net/items/e6a00/storage.swf" width="1" height="1">
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
    <param name="flashvars" value="logfn=_GPL.items.e6a00.log&amp;onload=_GPL.items.e6a00.onload&amp;onerror=_GPL.items.e6a00.onerror&amp;LSOName=gpl">
  </object>
</div>
```

I've run global searches for all of the keywords in the HTML but it's nowhere to be found in my project.

After that I tried disabling all of the external plugins I load, including Facebook's SDK, Mixpanel, Google Analytics, but it still shows up.

What else can I do to find the culprit?

Comment: [this was interesting](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/topic467670.html) - savingsslider-a.akamaihd.net appears to be associated with malware

Comment: Weird — what is it then???
@Kyle thanks for the edit :)

Comment: It sounds like your browser is the issue. Post the link to your site.

Comment: Related: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=621&t=764701#p2932337

Comment: @DonovanGlover That's the answer — it's a Chrome extension. I also had an Ebay and Amazon extension installed without my knowing... I swear I haven't watched porn in a while... but the answer to this is that it's the "Savings Slider" plugin for Chrome. Mind posting it?

Comment: Is your page supposed to be running a Flash video/app?  If not then *something* has been hacked.  But not necessarily your app/website.

Comment: @Garrett I did not find an official version in the Chrome Web Store (or Firefox Add-ons), but they do have a homepage: hxtp://savings-slider.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using FTP to upload your files, use an FTP client that can compare the local and remote files (my preference is FileZilla). Using this, you can find any files on the server that have been modified, and hopefully find and remove the problem.

Alternatively you could just re-upload the whole thing from your local copy.

Comment: I just found that it's on my live site (and as stated before, it is also on my local copy). However, scanners don't detect it because it's inserted into the DOM after pageload with a few seconds delay :S

Comment: How did it get on your local copy?

Comment: I do stream online tv shows, so one of the sites must've installed the extensions without my consent, somehow. The culprit is an extension called "Savings Slider". Some googling shows that this extension has quite the reputation for being downloaded unknowingly. I wonder if there's a way to report them...

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar thing on a client's computer. After some research, it looks like it is due to "vuze" installing add-ons or extensions to your browser (and probably not in your code).

We think this because all of the installed add-ons and extensions match those in vuze's uninstallation instructions: http://www.vuze.com/uninstall-vuze-mac-extensions.php

Answer (score 0):

A plugin for Firefox called Flashblock made a hidden Flash file become visible. I rolled over the Flash icon (displayed where the hidden Flash file is located -- top left corner of every browser page). I then saw the URL just like the one you encountered: savingsslider-a.akamaihd.net/items/e6a00/storage.swf 
I was upset about this but then I searched online for savingsslider and discovered it was another Firefox plugin (that I don't remember installing). But I removed it and re-started my Firefox and things went back to normal. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It comes from "unwanted" extensions being enabled on your browser and most likely comes with software that you just keep clicking "next" on with out reading.

Check your extensions and disabled/remove the ones you don't know about.

[How to edit browser extensions](http://help.yahoo.com/kb/index?locale=en_US&page=content&y=PROD_GRPS&id=SLN3016)